# "npm update" breaks package.json of updated module that is pulled from github, and causes push to Heroku to break

Tags: git, heroku, github, npm, package.json

I have an unpublished module, that is hosted on github. I specify the module in my project's package.json with the following line:

```
"module-to-load": "https://xyz-automation:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev"
```

When my colleague runs `npm update`, which grabs the `module-to-load` from github, the package.json for the `module-to-load` looks like this:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-toload.git#dev",
      "/Users/Bob/Documents/path/..."
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
  "_id": "module-to-load@1.0.24",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/module-to-load",
  "_phantomChildren": {
    "joi": "6.10.1",
    "jws": "3.1.3",
    "lodash.once": "4.1.1",
    "moment": "2.15.1",
    "ms": "0.7.1",
    "xtend": "4.0.1"
  },
  "_requested": {
    "hosted": {
      "directUrl": "https://module-to-load:xyz123...@raw.githubusercontent.com/XYZ/module-to-load/dev/package.json",
      "gitUrl": "git://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
      "httpsUrl": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
      "shortcut": "github:XYZ/module-to-load#dev",
      "ssh": "git@github.com:XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
      "sshUrl": "git+ssh://git@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
      "type": "github"
    },
    "name": null,
    "raw": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
    "rawSpec": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
    "scope": null,
    "spec": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
    "type": "hosted"
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "/"
  ],
  "_resolved": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#9ab...",
  "_shasum": "537...",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
  "_where": "/Users/Bob/Documents/path/...",
  "author": {
    "name": "John"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aguid": "^1.0.4",
    "arrford": "^2.0.1",
    "cron": "^1.1.0",
    "csvtojson": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase": "^3.0.5",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.1",
    "fuzzyset.js": "0.0.1",
    "ignore-case": "^0.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.5",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "string_score": "^0.1.22"
  },
  "description": "description...",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "gitHead": "9ab...",
  "installable": true,
  "main": "index.js",
  "name": "module-to-load",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "version": "1.0.24"
}
```

When the package.json for `module-to-load` is presented as its shown above, I can do a push to Heroku and everything works correctly on Heroku.

When I run `npm update` on my local machine, the package.json for `module-to-load` ends up looking like the following, and when I do a push to Heroku I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/module-to-load
remote:        npm ERR! 404
remote:        npm ERR! 404  'module-to-load' is not in the npm registry.
remote:        npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
remote:        npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'XYZ_demo'
remote:        npm ERR! 404
remote:        npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
remote:        npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Here is the package.json for `module-to-load` which breaks Heroku, and results from me running `npm update` vs my colleague running `npm update`:

```
{
  "_args": [
    [
      {
        "raw": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
        "scope": null,
        "escapedName": null,
        "name": null,
        "rawSpec": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
        "spec": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
        "type": "hosted",
        "hosted": {
          "type": "github",
          "ssh": "git@github.com:XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
          "sshUrl": "git+ssh://git@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
          "httpsUrl": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
          "gitUrl": "git://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
          "shortcut": "github:XYZ/module-to-load#dev",
          "directUrl": "https://module-to-load:xyz123...@raw.githubusercontent.com/XYZ/module-to-load/dev/package.json"
        }
      },
      "/Users/John/Documents/path/..."
    ]
  ],
  "_from": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
  "_id": "module-to-load@1.0.32",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_installable": true,
  "_location": "/module-to-load",
  "_phantomChildren": {
    "joi": "6.10.1",
    "jws": "3.1.3",
    "lodash.once": "4.1.1",
    "moment": "2.15.1",
    "ms": "0.7.1",
    "xtend": "4.0.1"
  },
  "_requested": {
    "raw": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
    "scope": null,
    "escapedName": null,
    "name": null,
    "rawSpec": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
    "spec": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
    "type": "hosted",
    "hosted": {
      "type": "github",
      "ssh": "git@github.com:XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
      "sshUrl": "git+ssh://git@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
      "httpsUrl": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
      "gitUrl": "git://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
      "shortcut": "github:XYZ/module-to-load#dev",
      "directUrl": "https://module-to-load:xyz123...@raw.githubusercontent.com/XYZ/module-to-load/dev/package.json"
    }
  },
  "_requiredBy": [
    "#USER",
    "/"
  ],
  "_resolved": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#a7c...",
  "_shasum": "d38...",
  "_shrinkwrap": null,
  "_spec": "git+https://module-to-load:xyz123...@github.com/XYZ/module-to-load.git#dev",
  "_where": "/Users/John/Documents/path/...",
  "author": {
    "name": "John"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aguid": "^1.0.4",
    "arrford": "^2.0.1",
    "cron": "^1.1.0",
    "csvtojson": "^1.0.0",
    "firebase": "^3.0.5",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.1",
    "fuzzyset.js": "0.0.1",
    "ignore-case": "^0.1.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^7.1.9",
    "lodash": "^4.14.0",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.5",
    "node-uuid": "^1.4.7",
    "request": "^2.72.0",
    "string_score": "^0.1.22"
  },
  "description": "Router and Content for SBT Bots",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "gitHead": "a7c...",
  "main": "index.js",
  "name": "module-to-load",
  "optionalDependencies": {},
  "version": "1.0.32"
}
```

Why is it that when I run `npm update` the package.json for `module-to-update` causes the push to Heroku to break? What can I do so I can run `npm update` locally and then be able to push to Heroku like my colleague is able to do?

I'm pushing my entire `node_modules` directory to Heroku, so there is no chance of different behavior between my local machine and the remote Heroku server. I may decide to ignore `node_modules` in the future, but for right now I'm trying to push the entire `node_modules` to Heroku.